# Hi I would like to create a Quiz with actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So what I  have is  ,  I have 20 questions and 5 answers of these questions ,  What I want to achieve is to get the answers uniquely ,  there will be

```
" a , b , c, d, e "
```

to choose for every question.

Everytime user enters the quiz , all the questions and answers will be loaded uniqely.

My main problem is I cant get  unique answers ,
For example ,  for question 1

```
What is the day
```

I end up with same answers

```
a )  monday   b) tuesday c) monday d)thursday e) saturday.....
```

I cant load different uniqe answers..

how is that possible , I tried  splice array   but it only makes things messed up.

Comment: Create an array of answers, and a function that randomly selects 5 answers from the array.

Comment: Can you show us the code that fails?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this..**

```
var anwers:Array = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var selectedAnswers:Array = new Array(5);       // array for selected answers
var tmp:Number = Math.floor(Math.random*5);
var correct:String  = answers[0];               // let "Monday" be the correct answer
selectedAnswers[tmp] = correct;                 // correct answer set to a random position 

for(var i:Number=0; i<5; i++){
    tmp=Math.floor(Math.random*5);
    if(selectedAnswers[i].equals(correct)) continue;  //skip  for the correct answer
    if(selectedAnswers.indexOf(answers[tmp])<0){      // set answer if not present already
        selectedAnswers[i] = answers[tmp];
    } else {
        i--;                                          // loop again if answer is set earlier
    }
}
```

Above will be completely random, but may take some time to select the last elements..

---

**The following method will be quite fast, but not fully random**

```
var anwers:Array = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var selectedAnswers:Array = new Array(5);       // array for selected answers
var tmp:Number = Math.floor(Math.random*5);
var correctIndex:Number = 0;                    // let "Monday" be the correct answer
var correct:String  = answers[correctIndex];                
selectedAnswers[tmp] = correct;                 // correct answer set to a random position 
var j:Number = correctIndex;                    // temporary index
var offset:Number = 2;                          // unique for this answer set
                                                // so that the answers won't overlap for 5 choices

for(var i:Number=0; i<4; i++){                  // not completely random (yet give random answers for specific cases)
    tmp++;      
    if(tmp==5) tmp = 0;
    j += offset;
    if(j>answers.length) j -= answers.length;
    selectedAnswers[tmp] = answers[j];
}
```

This assigns values from `answers` to `selectedAnswers` starting from a random index;